# Distortions appear on the high-poly boots with meshs deform

Tags: animation, mesh, armature

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UCbl.jpg)[image]I made high poly boots. I tied them to the low poly model with the help of mesh deformations. During animation, when my character rotates 180 degrees, strange distortions appear on the high-poly boots. Maybe someone faced a similar problem?
High poly boots are tied to low poly boots. Low-poly boots tied to rebar.[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you please edit your question to add a picture of what the boots look like before they distort?

Comment: I don't know how to edit my question or add a photo to the answer. So I'll give you a link with screenshots. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1a16QyLUE7S3ZwhaNXSqItgWCiCLQzGPd?usp=share_link

Comment: There should be a button labeled "Edit" in the bottom left corner below your question.